# What are the Covid check procedures at arrival on Spain?

Tags: covid-19, spain

My romantic partner is arriving this weekend in Spain from the US, and one of their roommates has been infected with Covid. They're isolating and have tested negative, but to dissuade worries: **What is the procedure of Covid checking when arriving at the country?** They have their booster done and will sign up the necessary online paperwork with their proof of vaccination once the time comes, but we're worried the virus is incubating and will manifest itself during the plane flight or something silly and unlikely like that. Hence this question.

Any sort of official documentation or first hand information of people that have gone through the border and did get tested/didn't get tested, etc, would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: You want to test for your own peace of mind, or you are asking about any mandatory tests?

Comment: @AnishSheela Any mandatory tests that are done at the border, whether you have symptoms or not. We are worried that after filing the paperwork at the 72 hours before flight and then having the virus emerge after incubating or somesuch.

Comment: I wish someone who actually traveled recently say their experience, the docs on the web are conflicting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spain Travel Health (SpTH) and the Ministerio De Sanidad, Spain have set a few airport controls according to [this site.](https://www.sanidad.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/sanidadExterior/ControlHS.htm)

> El control primario consiste en lo siguiente:
>
> Toma de temperatura
> mediante termómetros sin contacto o por cámaras termográficas.
>
> Control visual
> sobre el estado del pasajero.
>
> Control documental
> Se realiza mediante la comprobación del Certificado COVID Digital UE (CCD UE) / >Equivalente UE del que disponga el pasajero (vacunación, recuperación o prueba >diagnóstica de COVID-19) o del Formulario de Control Sanitario (FCS) cumplimentado >por el viajero antes de llegar a España a través de la página web https://www.spth.gob.es/ , donde obtendrá un QR-SpTH. Sólo será necesario cumplimentar el FCS de SpTH si llega a España por vía aérea.
>
> A la llegada a España le podrá ser requerida la presentación de su CCD >UE/Equivalente UE o el código QR-SpTH en los lectores de códigos QR >ubicados en los puestos de control sanitario.
>
> Los menores de 12 años y los pasajeros en tránsito internacional no tienen >que presentar un certificado ni el QR de SpTH.

Translation:

> Primary control consists in the following:
>
> Temperature taking via a thermometer without contact or via
> thermographic cameras.
>
> Visual control over the passenger's state.
>
> Documental control: It will be performed via the checking of the COVID
> Digital EU Certificate (CCD UE) / EU Equivalent that the passenger
> has. (Vaccination, recuperation or diagnostic Covid-19 test) or the
> Sanitary Control Form (FCS) filled in by the traveller through the
> website https://www.spth.gob.es/ , where a QR-SpTH will be obtained.
> It is only necessary to fill the SpTH FCS if you arrive to Spain via
> air.
>
> When arriving to Spain it may be required the presentation of the CCD
> UE / EU Equivalent or the QR-SpTH code in the QR code readers ubicated
> in the sanitary control points. Minors under 12 years old and
> passengers in international transit don't have to present a QR
> certificate nor the SpTH one.

While if you are presenting symptoms or if you are randomly chosen, you go through a secondary control:

> Si durante el control primario (en cualquiera de los casos previamente
> descritos) se detecta un pasajero sospechoso de padecer COVID-19
> (temperatura superior a 37,5 ºC, presencia de síntomas de estar
> enfermo), deberá ser derivado al control secundario donde se realizará
> una valoración más exhaustiva.
>
> Tanto en el proceso de evaluación médica, así como si la autoridad
> sanitaria competente lo considera oportuno en base al marco de
> vigilancia activa vinculada a procesos de evaluación del riesgo, se le
> podrá realizar una Prueba Diagnóstica de Infección Activa (PDIA).
>
> Si tras el control sanitario se confirma la sospecha de que usted
> pudiera padecer una patología con riesgo para la salud pública, si se
> trata de un contacto estrecho de COVID-19 o si se obtiene un resultado
> positivo tras la realización de una PDIA para SRAS-CoV-2 a la llegada,
> se activarán los protocolos establecidos en coordinación con las
> autoridades sanitarias de las comunidades autónomas. Para ello la
> autoridad sanitaria podrá solicitar la colaboración de otros órganos
> administrativos, funcionarios públicos u otras instituciones.
>
> La información personal que se emplee en las actuaciones de salud
> pública se regirá por lo dispuesto en el  Reglamento (UE) 2016/679 del
> Parlamento Europeo y del Consejo, de 27 de abril de 2016, relativo a
> la protección de las personas físicas en lo que respecta al
> tratamiento de sus datos personales y a la libre circulación de estos
> datos y la Ley Orgánica 3/2018, de 5 de diciembre, de Protección de
> Datos Personales y Garantía de los Derechos Digitales y otras
> reglamentaciones relacionadas y en la Ley 41/2002, de 14 de noviembre,
> Básica reguladora de la Autonomía del Paciente y de Derechos y
> Obligaciones en materia de Información y Documentación Clínica.

Translation:

> If during the primary control (In any of the cases previously
> described) a passenger suspicious of being infected of COVID-19 is
> detected (Temperature over 37,5 ºC, symptoms of being ill), it will be
> sent to the secondary control where a more exhaustive check will be
> performed.
>
> In the medical evaluation process as well as if the right sanitary
> authority will consider it applicable in regards to the active
> vigilance protocol linked to risk evaluation processes, an Active
> Infection Diagnostics Test may be performed on you (PDIA)
>
> If after the sanitary control, it is confirmed the suspicion that you
> could be infected with a pathology with risk for public health if it
> is regards to a close contact of COVID-19 or if a positive result is
> obtained after the performing of a PDIA for SRAS-CoV-2 upon arrival,
> stablished protocols in coordination with sanitary Comunidad Autonomas
> authorities will be activated. For that, the sanitary authority may
> solicit the colaboration of other administrative body, public workers,
> or other institutions.
>
> The personal information that may be employed in the public health
> updates will be governed by the disposes in the Reglamento (UE)
> 2016/679 of the European Parliament and the Council, from April 27th,
> 2016, relative to the protection of physical persons in regards to the
> treatment of personal data, and the free circulation of of these data
> and the Ley Orgánica 3/2018, of December 5th, of Protección de Datos
> Personales y Garantía de los Derechos Digitales and other rulings
> related and in the Ley 41/2002, of November 14th, Básica reguladora de
> la Autonomía del Paciente y de Derechos y Obligaciones en materia de
> Información y Documentación Clínica.

Comment: I'll wait a day before accepting this answer.

Comment: This site is supposed to be up to date: https://reopen.europa.eu/en/from-to/OTC/ESP