# What happens if you test COVID positive at the Spanish border on arrival?

Tags: covid-19, spain

research continues, as per [this question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175646/what-are-the-covid-check-procedures-at-arrival-on-spain)

My partner got their booster very recently but more than 14 days ago, so they should be fine, as apparently you don't have to present a negative test if you have proof of full vaccination and booster. But *hypothetically* even if they tested positive, if they showed no symptoms, what would happen at the airport? I've been researching for hours, and it's no use, I only find mentions that there *may be* tests, but no explanation of what happens if it is positive! It seems like these documentation requirements and other tests are random of some kind, so even if you are positive, you may not even be tested.

So, in the *hypothetical* case that you are Covid Positive and you go ahead and arrive at the country (after filling the SpTH document), and you somehow pass through a random test, and you turn out positive, what would happen? Quarantine? Deportation at the border? (That would wild to me, considering how tourist-hungry Spain is.)

Thank you. We are rather anxious, and we'd like to dissuade these anxieties with **new, recent** information, either from first hand experience or any official documents (BOE, etc). Second hand experience is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling multiple places, culminating in a call to AENA, I have found out:

If you arrive and you go through a covid test and it turns out positive, depending on the area you are at, you may be subjected from 0 to 5 days of confinement at the place you were going to stay. No deporting, or staying at the airport or anything like that.

I wish I had more information than a phone call, including some quotes, but the fact is, this information is nowhere online that I could find after many many many hours of searching.

Comment: I hesitate putting this answer as Accepted due to how flimsy it is, even if it's the only concrete information I've ever found. I'll wait a day.

Comment: It is obvious actually. You are afraid of deporting but that is kidding. Obviously the option would be quatantine in case they really test

Comment: @AhmadTurani Yes, but without concrete information, the mind wanders into unsavoury places sometimes. Better to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The official website of spain isn't that clear, when it is about arrival in spain with a positive test.

According to the travel advise website of the UK:

> If you have symptoms or test positive for COVID-19 during your stay in Spain, you are not required to self-isolate but you should inform direct contacts and take the following extra precautionary measures for 10 days from diagnosis or from when symptoms began:
>
> - wear a mask
> - reduce social interactions and avoid crowded spaces & large events
> - avoid contact with people at high risk (including older people, people with health conditions and pregnant women)

[UK Travel Advise](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/coronavirus)

The department of foreign affairs of ireland writes a similar statement and offers easy to see dates, when this information was updated (03.08.2022) .

> If you test positive for COVID-19 while on holiday in Spain, you may be required to isolate in line with local health requirements. Please note that not all regions of Spain have dedicated quarantine hotels or facilities for those who test positive for COVID-19, and you may need to contact your accommodation provider to arrange to extend your stay. Costs incurred from extending your stay in Spain are at the traveller’s own expense. As such, you are strongly advised to ensure that your insurance policy provides adequate cover in the event that you need to extend your stay in Spain due to a positive COVID-19 diagnosis.

[Department of foreign affair, ireland](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-countries/spain/)

Comment: +1 for the quotes, but as you mentioned, this doesn't show what happens if they test you *at the border* and you turn out positive. I'd guess you just isolate at your place of residence you were staying in but still, it's just guesswork...